# Count filtered data in Elasticsearch(ElasticClient nest)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElasticClient 2.4.4.

I have one query

```
var sample = client.Search<TestMenuItem>(s => s
            .Query(q =>
                q.Term(p => p.RegionSegments, "s1")
                && q.Term(p => p.RegionSegments, "s2")
                 && q.Term(p => p.RegionSegments, "s3")
            ));
```

than I wanted to count how many items are with RegionSegments = s1.
As I understand I should use Aggregations but cant find good example how solve this issue.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need a count of each of `s1`, `s2` and `s3` RegionSegment documents, then you can do a [`multi_search`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) for this, specifying a count [`search_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-search-type.html) for all

```
var multiSearchResponse = client.MultiSearch(ms => ms
    // this is the default index for multi_search. Can override
    // on each Search call if needed
    .Index<TestMenuItem>()
    // this is the default type for mulit_search. Can override
    // on each search call if needed
    .Type<TestMenuItem>()
    // this is the default search_type. Can override on
    // each search call if needed
    .SearchType(SearchType.Count)
    .Search<TestMenuItem>("s1", s => s
        .Query(q => +q.Term(p => p.RegionSegments, "s1"))
    )
    .Search<TestMenuItem>("s2", s => s
        .Query(q => +q.Term(p => p.RegionSegments, "s2"))
    )
    .Search<TestMenuItem>("s3", s => s
        .Query(q => +q.Term(p => p.RegionSegments, "s3"))
    )
);
```

This produces the following request

```
POST http://localhost:9200/testmenuitem-index/testmenuitem/_msearch?search_type=count 
{}
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"regionSegments":{"value":"s1"}}}]}}}
{}
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"regionSegments":{"value":"s2"}}}]}}}
{}
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"regionSegments":{"value":"s3"}}}]}}}
```

The to get the total for each search result is similar to the following

```
var s1Total = multiSearchResponse.GetResponse<TestMenuItem>("s1").Total;
```

Comment: not exactly. First I need to get some query result and then do calculation based on this query result.

Comment: RegionSegments is a string like this 's1 s2 s3' or 's3 s2'

Comment: is `RegionSegments` analyzed? Do you need to match *exactly* on `s1` or `s2` or `s3`?

Comment: Russ Cam, you are right, first match than do calculation based on this query result.

Comment: OK, I would map `RegionSegments` as a collection of `not_analyzed` strings. The query above will then give you a count as requested for each of each of the documents that have a `RegionSegments` value containing `s1`, `s2` and `s3`.

Comment: @user1541069 another way would be to use `.Search()` with [multiple filter aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/filter-aggregation.html) for each regionsegment you want a count over.